# Blockquote alternative for HTML email?

Tags: html, html-email

Hello and thank you for taking the time to look inside my post.

I am currently building an HTML email and I inherited some code to work with, my current issue is that there is a section on the email that was built using  tags and they are not display correctly on several email services.

What other alternatives do I have for blockquote?? I have added my code below for your reference, I need to keep the same look but make it work. Thanks a lot!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example Title</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> <!-- prevent automatic off-centered scaling in iOS -->

<style type="text/css">

    #outlook a { 
        padding:0; /* trigger read in browser link in Outlook */
    }   

    body, #bodyTable {
        width:100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; /* disable auto-enlarge of text in mobile */
        -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color:#eeeeee;
    }

    /* Outlook fixes */


    /* Styles */



    img, a img {
        display: block; /* Remove extra space */
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; /* image resize fix for IE */
    }


    #main td, p, #subs td {
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 22px;
        color: #505050;
    }

    blockquote {
        background:url('https://email.jmls.edu/USnews/2019/lawyering-skills/images/quote.png') left top no-repeat, url('https://email.jmls.edu/USnews/2019/lawyering-skills/images/endquote.png') right bottom no-repeat;
        background-color:#f8f8f8;
        padding: 30px 40px 30px 40px;
        margin: 14px 30px;
    }

    blockquote p {
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom:2px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14px;
    }




    /* mobile-specific styles */


</style>

<table width="100%" id="bodyTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" id="main" style="background-color: #ffffff; border:1px solid #444444;">
     <tbody>
<tr>
    <td>

         <tr>
          <td style="padding: 10px 15px 20px;">
            <blockquote><p>&ldquo;It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.&rdquo; </p>
            <p  style="text-align:right; font-weight:normal;">&mdash;Chicago </p></blockquote>

            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </td>

</tr>

     </tbody>
    </table>
    </table>



    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need assistance with an HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398405/need-assistance-with-an-html-email)

Comment: <pre> is very similar.