# Need assistance with an HTML email

Tags: html, html-email

I am currently building an HTML email and I inherited some code to work with, my current issue is that there is a section on the email that was built using tags and they are not display correctly on several email services.

What alternatives do I have for blockquote? I have added my code below for your reference, I need to keep the same look but make it work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example Title</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> <!-- prevent automatic off-centered scaling in iOS -->

<style type="text/css">

    #outlook a { 
        padding:0; /* trigger read in browser link in Outlook */
    }   

    body, #bodyTable {
        width:100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; /* disable auto-enlarge of text in mobile */
        -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color:#eeeeee;
    }

    /* Outlook fixes */


    /* Styles */



    img, a img {
        display: block; /* Remove extra space */
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; /* image resize fix for IE */
    }


    #main td, p, #subs td {
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 22px;
        color: #505050;
    }

    blockquote {
        background:url('https://email.jmls.edu/USnews/2019/lawyering-skills/images/quote.png') left top no-repeat, url('https://email.jmls.edu/USnews/2019/lawyering-skills/images/endquote.png') right bottom no-repeat;
        background-color:#f8f8f8;
        padding: 30px 40px 30px 40px;
        margin: 14px 30px;
    }

    blockquote p {
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom:2px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14px;
    }




    /* mobile-specific styles */


</style>

<table width="100%" id="bodyTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" id="main" style="background-color: #ffffff; border:1px solid #444444;">
     <tbody>
<tr>
    <td>

         <tr>
          <td style="padding: 10px 15px 20px;">
            <blockquote><p>&ldquo;It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.&rdquo; </p>
            <p  style="text-align:right; font-weight:normal;">&mdash;Chicago </p></blockquote>

            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </td>

</tr>

     </tbody>
    </table>
    </table>



    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: I would start with replacing `<blockquote>` with a plain `<div>`. Then update your CSS selectors from `blockquote` and `blockquote p` to `div` and `div p`. If you're going to have multiple `<div>`s, then you will have to add an ID and change your CSS to use the IDs. E-mail systems may ignore inline CSS as well, so the `style="..."` attributes in the HTML might need to be moved to CSS.

Comment: ...or just migrate to an e-mail platform like Send in Blue. One of the main draws of such services is to avoid the headaches of display inconsistency associated with HTML e-mail.

Comment: I tried replacing the blockquote for div but I am still having the same issue, everything is being stripped. Any clues of what is going on?

Comment: I noticed that everything is placed within the head tags. Could it be that some email services expect your table to be placed within body tags? <body>...</body>

Comment: Html emails need to be coded as tables and inline CSS. You can code it as a web page (with tables) and just use an online inliner to make the styles inline.